# What is the name of this fly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I've seen the following insect in Austria at the border to Bavaria ([high resolution](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2017-06-23-mindelheimer-klettersteig-12.jpg)). It was quite small. I would guess not longer than 1cm:

[image]

Could somebody identify it?

Comment: Type of robber fly perhaps?

Comment: Not a robber fly; I _think_ Empididae; doing a search on https://diptera.info/infusions/aw_forum_panel/search.php for that family name might suggest a deeper identification

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you :-) I like taking close-ups and this one was a lucky one. I almost touched the insect with my camera lens but it didn't move. A really professional photo model; I wish more insects were like this ;-) And usually I put those photographs under CC0 on Wikipedia Commons to make it easy to use them.

Comment: yes, definitely Empididae with that long "snout". (but i can't be more precise than that.) i've also notices that a lot of them seem to be nice and slow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could somebody identify it?

Sure, I'd be glad to help you with that!

The fly in question is indeed a member of the [*Empididae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empididae) family, and of the genus [*Empis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empis). I couldn't quite decide on the species, but it's either [*Tessellata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empis_tessellata) or [*Opaca*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empis_opaca) (with me leaning more towards *Tessellata*). This fly (genus) is commonly referred to as a "Dance Fly".

Empis Tessellata

[image: Empis Tessellata]

Empis Opaca

[image: Empis Opaca]